# API for Podcast: RSS to transcription

Tags: api, integration, free, podcast

i need to find a way to be able to get sound file from an podcast rss feed and automatically put it into a transcribing software (preferably free). Alternatively I need a way to check if a new video has been uploaded to a channel and transcibe it.

I tried Zapier but it didn't quite integrate with a transcription software called Grain.co alternatively otter.ai would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention where you wanted to put the transcription text once it was complete. For the purpose of this answer, I'll assume a public location is fine.

[Rev.com](https://ttps://www.rev.com/) is a popular transcription service. While the service isn't free, the costs are reasonable at.25 US cents per minute for automated transcription. You would pay about $4 for a 45-minute podcast.

My solution: Zapier takes podcast episodes and places them in Google Drive. Rev takes episodes from Google Drive and transcribes them for you (destination optional).

This is the [RSS audio file to Google Drive](https://zapier.com/apps/google-drive/integrations/rss/10192/store-new-files-from-rss-feed-items-on-google-drive) Zap I recommend using to get audio files from the podcast would appear in your Google Drive folder.

Then, you can use this [Google Drive to Rev.com](https://zapier.com/apps/google-drive/integrations/rev/7253/create-rev-transcription-orders-from-new-google-drive-files) Zap to automate the transcription.

Since you mentioned Zapier, they have a [good article noting transcription services](https://zapier.com/blog/best-transcription-apps/) such as [Trint](https://www.trint.com), [TranscribeMe](https://www.transcribeme.com) and others. However, since free was your preferred pricing, Rev + Zapier was the lowest combination I found.

There are alternatives to Zapier. One example is [Automatisch](https://automatisch.io/), but you need to install and run the software on your own hardware.